# Duda con hashmap

Tags: java, ordenamiento, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
List<DatosAutores> datosAutor= new ArrayList<DatosAutores>();
    
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("157","Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño","joaquin@me.com","Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional","4027","Derecho","6"));
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("157","Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño","joaquin@me.com","Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social","4296","Derecho","6"));
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("193","Carlos Arturo  Castro Castro","carlos@usbmed.edu.co","Palabra Clave (La Plata)","3505","Ciencias de la Información","23"));
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("198","Romeo  Rojas","romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx","Colombia Forestal","4239","Agrociencias","28"));
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("198","Romeo  Rojas","romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx","Facultad de Ingeniería","4139","Ingeniería","38"));
    datosAutor.add(new DatosAutores("198","Romeo  Rojas","romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx","Sociedad y mundo","1211","Sociologia","10"));
```

**¿Cómo puedo obtener algo como el código siguiente?**

```
     /*  157  
     * Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño
     * joaquin@me.com
     * Derecho (area:6)
     *   Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional (clave:4027)
     *   Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social (clave:4296)
     * 
     * 
     * 198
     * Romeo  Rojas
     * romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx
     * Agrociencias (area:28)
     *    Colombia Forestal (clave:4239)
     * Ingeniería  (area:38)
     *    Facultad de Ingeniería (clave:4139)
     * Sociologia (area:10)
     *     Sociedad y mundo (clave:1211)
     * 
     * 193
     * Carlos Arturo  Castro Castro
     * carlos@usbmed.edu.co
     * Ciencias de la Información (area:23)
     *    Palabra Clave (La Plata)(clave:3505)
     */
```

He usado hashmap para ordenar la salida:

```
Set<String> duplicado = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    
    HashMap<DatosAutores,String> uno= new HashMap<DatosAutores,String>();
    HashMap<DatosAutores,String> dos= new HashMap<DatosAutores,String>();
    
    
    
    
    for(DatosAutores aut: datosAutor){
        if (!set.add(aut.getIdAutor())) {
            duplicado.add(aut.getIdAutor());
            out.println("##"+aut.getIdAutor());
            out.println(aut.getNomAutor());
            out.println(aut.getCorreo());
            out.println(aut.getNombreArea()+" - "+ aut.getClaveArea());
            out.println(".."+aut.getTituloRevista()+" - " +aut.getClaveRevista()+"");
            uno.put(aut,aut.getIdAutor());
        }
        else{
        out.println("**"+aut.getIdAutor()+ " no duplicado");
        out.println(aut.getNomAutor());
        out.println(aut.getCorreo());
        out.println(aut.getNombreArea()+" - "+ aut.getClaveArea());
        out.println(".."+aut.getTituloRevista()+" - "+aut.getClaveRevista()+"");
        dos.put(aut,aut.getIdAutor());
        }
    }
    out.println("duplicado:"+duplicado);
    out.println("set:"+set);
    
    
    for (Entry<DatosAutores,String> entry : uno.entrySet()) {
        DatosAutores key = entry.getKey();
        String value = (String) entry.getValue();
        for (Entry<DatosAutores,String> entry2 : dos.entrySet()) {
            DatosAutores key2 = entry2.getKey();
            String value2 = (String) entry2.getValue();
            
            if(key.getIdAutor().equals(key2.getIdAutor())){
                out.println(key2.getIdAutor()+","+key2.getNomAutor());
                out.println(key2.getCorreo());
                out.println(key.getNombreArea() +" -- "+key2.getNombreArea());
                out.println(key.getTituloRevista()+" -- "+key.getClaveRevista()+", "   +key2.getTituloRevista()+" --- "+key2.getClaveRevista());
                
            }
            
            
        }//fin for 2
        
    }//fin for 1
```

Comment: cuál es la duda?

Comment: ¿Y no hay ninguna duda solo veías a presumirnos tu código? :P

Comment: La duda es como obtener el orden de este modo:

/*  157  
     * Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño
     * joaquin@me.com
     * Derecho (area:6)
     *   Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional (clave:4027)
     *   Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social (clave:4296)

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que obtienes hasta ahora? ¿Cuál es el error específico?, y ¿qué parte exactamente es la que no está funcionando correctamente?

Comment: lo que quieres es ordenar los objetos de la lista, en base al id?

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente código genera un salida semejante a la que tú requieres:

- *Código:*

  ```java
  // Cargar datos
  Set<String> autorSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  Map<String, Set<String>> areaMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  Map<String, Set<String>> revistaMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  for (DatosAutores aut : datosAutor) {
      String idAutor = aut.getIdAutor();
      autorSet.add(idAutor);
      if (!areaMap.containsKey(idAutor)) {
          areaMap.put(idAutor, new LinkedHashSet<String>());
      }
      String claveArea = aut.getClaveArea();
      areaMap.get(idAutor).add(claveArea);
      if (!revistaMap.containsKey(claveArea)) {
          revistaMap.put(claveArea, new LinkedHashSet<String>());
      }
      String claveRevista = aut.getClaveRevista();
      revistaMap.get(claveArea).add(claveRevista);
  }

  // Imprimir datos
  for(String idAutor : autorSet) {
      DatosAutores aut = null;
      for(DatosAutores temp : datosAutor) {
          if (idAutor.equals(temp.getIdAutor())) {
              aut = temp;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (aut != null) {
          System.out.println(idAutor);
          System.out.println(aut.getNomAutor());
          System.out.println(aut.getCorreo());
      }
      for(String claveArea : areaMap.get(idAutor)) {
          for(DatosAutores temp : datosAutor) {
              if (idAutor.equals(temp.getIdAutor()) && claveArea.equals(temp.getClaveArea())) {
                  System.out.printf("%s (area:%s)%n", temp.getNombreArea(), claveArea);
              }

          }
          for(String claveRevista : revistaMap.get(claveArea)) {
              for(DatosAutores temp : datosAutor) {
                  if (claveRevista.equals(temp.getClaveRevista())) {
                      System.out.printf("  %s (clave:%s)%n", temp.getTituloRevista(), claveRevista);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
  }
  ```
- *Salida:*

  ```
  157
  Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño
  joaquin@me.com
  Derecho (area:6)
  Derecho (area:6)
    Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional (clave:4027)
    Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social (clave:4296)

  193
  Carlos Arturo  Castro Castro
  carlos@usbmed.edu.co
  Ciencias de la Información (area:23)
    Palabra Clave (La Plata) (clave:3505)

  198
  Romeo  Rojas
  romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx
  Agrociencias (area:28)
    Colombia Forestal (clave:4239)
  Ingeniería (area:38)
    Facultad de Ingeniería (clave:4139)
  Sociologia (area:10)
    Sociedad y mundo (clave:1211)
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias Paul Vargas. Algo así requiero mostrar.  Tenia en mente crear un HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> mapa= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>  

De tal manera que el área quedara como "llave" y la revista/clave formaran parte del otro hash

Derecho 
   .. Titulo
   ... Clave
Ingeniería
  ... Título

Answer (score 2):

Una correcta elección de estructura de datos facilitará mucho tu trabajo.

Ahora tienes una clase `DatosAutores` que contiene un autor, un área y una revista. Y una lista en que se almacenan esos autores tal que así :

```
Lista
|-DatosAutores
|    |- "157"
|    |- "Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño"
|    |- "joaquin@me.com"
|    |- "Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional"
|    |- "4027"
|    |-"Derecho"
|    \- "6"
|-DatosAutores
|    |- "157"
|    |- "Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño"
|    |- "joaquin@me.com"
|    |- "Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social"
|    |- "4296"
|    |- "Derecho"
|    \- "6"
. 
.
```

Con esa estructura solo puedes almacenar un área y una revista en cada DatosAutores, lo que hace que tenga que repetirse el autor y las áreas múltiples veces.

Una estructura más apropiada sería la siguiente.

```
Datos :
|- autores : Map<String, DatosAutores>
  |- "157", DatosAutores
  |         |- "Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño"
  |         |- "joaquin@me.com"
  |         \- areas - Map<String, DatosAreas> 
  |             \- "6", DatosAreas
  |                       |-"Derecho"
  |                       \- revistas - Map<String, String>
  |                          |- "4027", "Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional"
  |                          \- "4296", "Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social"
  |
  |- "198", DatosAutores
  |         |- "Romeo  Rojas"
  .         .
  .         .
```

Con esa estructura solo has de almacenar cada autor una vez.
Y para cada autor solo has de almacenar cada una de las áreas en que tiene revistas una sola vez.

Datos contiene un Map usando como clave(key) la clave String clave del autor; y como valor(value) un objeto de clase DatosAutores.
DatosAutores contiene el nombre y el email; y un Map usando como clave(key) la clave de las areas y como valor(value) un objeto de clase DatosAreas.
Y Datos Areas contiene el nombre del área; y un Map usando como clave(key) la clave de la revista y como valor(value) el nombre de la revista.

El código para DatosAreas sería :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class DatosAreas {
    private final String nombre;
    private final Map<String,String> revistas;

    public DatosAreas( String nombre)
    {
        if ( nombre==null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "nombre debe ser no null");
        this.nombre = nombre;
        revistas = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void añadeRevista( String nombre, String clave )
    {
        if ( nombre==null || clave==null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "nombre y clave deben ser no null");
        revistas.put( clave, nombre);
    }

    public String toString( String clave )
    {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        res.append( "  ").append(nombre).append(" (area:").append(clave)
           .append(")").append(System.lineSeparator());
        for ( Map.Entry<String,String> r : revistas.entrySet() )
        {
            res.append("    ").append(r.getValue()).append(" (clave:")
               .append(r.getKey()).append(")").append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

El constructor sencillamente asigna el nombre del áreas, crea un HashMap vacío y comprueba que el nombre no sea null.
`añadeRevista` comprueba que nombre y clave de revista no sean null. Y luego llama a `put` de HashMap para añadir la revista. **`Hashmap.put` trata el caso de que añadamos la misma clave de revista dos veces**. La segunda vez se tratará como una actualización, no se añade repetida la revista sino que se cambia el título al de la segunda llamada.
Y `toString(String clave)` devuelve una `String` con los datos del área y las revistas que en ella hay.

El código de DatosAutores sería :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class DatosAutores {

    private final String nombre;
    private final String email;
    private final Map<String, DatosAreas> areas;

    public DatosAutores( String nombre, String email )
    {
        if ( nombre==null || email==null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Nombre y email han de ser no null");
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.email = email;
        areas = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void añadeRevista( String nombreArea, String claveArea,
            String nombreRevista, String claveRevista )
    {
        DatosAreas area;
        area = areas.get(claveArea);
        if ( area==null )
        {
            area = new DatosAreas(nombreArea);
            areas.put(claveArea, area);
        }
        area.añadeRevista(nombreRevista, claveRevista);
    }

    public String toString( String clave )
    {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        res.append(clave).append(System.lineSeparator());
        res.append(nombre).append(System.lineSeparator());
        res.append(email).append(System.lineSeparator());
        for ( Map.Entry<String,DatosAreas> a : areas.entrySet() )
        {
            res.append( a.getValue().toString( a.getKey() ));
        }
        res.append(System.lineSeparator());
        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

El constructor asigna nombre y email comprobando que no son null; y crea un HashMap nuevo.
`añadeRevista` comprueba si ya existe ese área en el `Map` de áreas del autor. Si no crea una nueva área. Y añade a ese área (la nueva o la que ya existía) la revista. 
`toString(String clave)` genera una `String` con los datos del autor y los datos de cada áreas; los cuales obtiene llamando a `toString` de cáda área, que ya hemos definido antes.

Finalmente la clase Datos :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Datos {
    private final Map<String, DatosAutores> autores;
    public Datos()
    {
        autores = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void add( String claveAutor, String nombreAutor, String email,
            String nombreRevista, String claveRevista, 
            String nombreArea, String claveArea)
    {
        DatosAutores dato = autores.get( claveAutor );
        if ( dato==null )
        {
            dato = new DatosAutores(nombreAutor, email);
            autores.put(claveAutor, dato);
        }
        dato.añadeRevista(nombreArea, claveArea, nombreRevista, claveRevista);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        for ( Map.Entry<String,DatosAutores> autor : autores.entrySet() )
        {
            res.append( autor.getValue().toString( autor.getKey() ));
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

El constructor simplemente crea un nuevo HashMap.
`add` comprueba si ya tenemos ese autor, si no lo crea y añade; y después añade la revista al autor.
`toString` llama al método `toString` de todos los autores y junta el resultado para tener una cadena con todos los autores, sus áreas y revistas.

Con esa estructura de datos el añadir e imprimir revistas organizadas se reduce a :

```
Datos datosAutor = new Datos();
datosAutor.add( "157", "Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño", "joaquin@me.com", "Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional", "4027", "Derecho", "6");
datosAutor.add( "157", "Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño", "joaquin@me.com", "Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social", "4296", "Derecho", "6");
datosAutor.add( "193", "Carlos Arturo  Castro Castro", "carlos@usbmed.edu.co", "Palabra Clave (La Plata)", "3505", "Ciencias de la Información", "23");
datosAutor.add( "198", "Romeo  Rojas", "romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx", "Colombia Forestal", "4239", "Agrociencias", "28");
datosAutor.add( "198", "Romeo  Rojas", "romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx", "Facultad de Ingeniería", "4139", "Ingeniería", "38");
datosAutor.add( "198", "Romeo  Rojas", "romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx", "Sociedad y mundo", "1211", "Sociologia", "10");
System.out.println( datosAutor );
```

Obteniendo como resultado :

```
198
Romeo  Rojas
romeo.rojasm@uanl.edu.mx
  Ingeniería (area:38)
    Facultad de Ingeniería (clave:4139)
  Agrociencias (area:28)
    Colombia Forestal (clave:4239)
  Sociologia (area:10)
    Sociedad y mundo (clave:1211)

157
Joaquín  Ordóñez Sedeño
joaquin@me.com
  Derecho (area:6)
    Revista Latinoamericana de Derecho Social (clave:4296)
    Anuario Mexicano de Derecho Internacional (clave:4027)

193
Carlos Arturo  Castro Castro
carlos@usbmed.edu.co
  Ciencias de la Información (area:23)
    Palabra Clave (La Plata) (clave:3505)
```

La propia estructura de datos ya lo organiza todo. No es necesario un código de bucles comprobando si hay o no repeticiones y buscando datos dispersos.
Al tener una buena organización de datos la impresión resulta sencilla.

Comment: Gracias Jose Antonio Dura Olmos.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Gracias a todos pos sus respuestas.